# trouble configuring timings for LVDS display (linux on rk3288)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I'm trying to hook up an LVDS display to my dev board based on rockchip rk3288 and have trouble getting graphics to show on the display.

The display is the GWTS80MNFG1E0 by SGD. The datasheet is here http://www.datadisplay-group.com/fileadmin/pdf/produkte/Displays/SGD/GWTS80MNFG1E0_Datasheet.pdf

Here  is the .dtsi file I created for the display:

```
/ {

                disp_timings: display-timings {
                        native-mode = <&timing0>;
                        timing0: timing0 {
                                screen-type = <SCREEN_LVDS>;
                                lvds-format = <LVDS_8BIT_1>;
                                out-face    = <OUT_P888>;
                                clock-frequency = <48690000 52590000 60830000>;
                                hactive = <1656 1660 1760>;
                                vactive = <490 528 576>;
                                hback-porch = <5 16 141>;
                                hfront-porch = <19 44 155>;
                                vback-porch = <5 5 91>;
                                vfront-porch = <5 43 91>;
                                hsync-len = <1 2 140>;
                                vsync-len = <1 2 90>;
                                hsync-active = <0>;
                                vsync-active = <0>;
                                de-active = <1>;
                                pixelclk-active = <0>;
                                swap-rb = <0>;
                                swap-rg = <0>;
                                swap-gb = <0>;
                        };
               };
};
```

The problem is that the display turns on but I can't see any graphics. In the .config file for the kernel I have CONFIG_RK32_LVDS=y. The .dts file for the board includes my .dtsi file.

**Hardware details:**

On my breadboard, interfacing my dev board to the display, I've pulled STBYB, RESET, SELB, RL, and TB high via a 10k pullup to 3.3v.

For backlight I'm using the adafruit tft friend - https://www.adafruit.com/product/1932 
I'm taking 5v from my dev board to feed the backlight driver and I've hooked up LED- and LED+ of the display to the backlight driver. The driver is configured to output 75mA at the moment. The adafruit board has specs of outputting up to 125mA at 24V while the SGD datasheet mentions 25.6V. I'm not sure if this is a problem or not.

I have the VSDN/VSDP hooked up to a TPS65132WEVM-669 (texas instruments) which I've programmed to provide +/- 5.5v. This EVM is powered from the same 5v as the backlight driver. I've verified it's outputting the correct voltages.

I've hooked up the display inputs RXIN[0123]+/- to board lvds port outputs D[0123]P/N. Display clock inputs RXCLKIN+/- are hooked up to board lvds port clock lines CLK0P/N.

**My questions:**

1) is the backlight driver the problem here? 
2) is the .dtsi file I created for the display correct? 
3) is there anything else I can check w/r/t my kernel / dts config or the hardware itself?

Thanks
B

Answer (score 1):

There are five items which need to be verified:

LVDS settings in dts:

1. Check the IPU channel which is correctly mapped on the lvds device
2. data-width (18bit/24bit) of the lvds channel.
3. LVDS output format for serializer (VESA or Non-VESA format )

Frame buffer settings in dts:

Check your frame buffer settings
         - bit pet pixels
         - Pixel format
         - ipu clock

Kernel command:

Check whether any of the kernel command which is overwrite the dtsi settings during kernel startup.

Backlight:

In order to make the backlight, measure the display current.

Lock:

Check the physical connection between serializer and deserializer. Make sure the LOCK signal.

Answer (score -1):

I had as similar issue after a kernel update, and this kernel "fix" was the problem. Newer kernels (after 2013) fall back on not having any LVDS screen, which mean that you don't see any graphics.

http://marc.info/?l=git-commits-head&m=138449380916013&w=2